# Does equality of ranges of $fh$ and $gh$ for all $h$ continuous imply equality of $f$ and $g$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and suppose Range($fh$)=Range($gh$) $\forall h\in C(X), f, g$ also in $C(X)$. The question is whether this implies that $f=g$. Let us for the time being assume that the continuous functions are real valued.

I don't want a solution to this question itself, but I'd like a clarification on the following.

Suppose $f\neq g$. Then there exists $x_{0}\in X$ such that $f(x_{0})\neq g(x_{0})$. Using the Hausdorff property of the scalar field (in this case, $\mathbb{R}$) we can then find an open set $U\subset X$ such that $f(U)\cap g(U)=\emptyset$.

Now WLOG we can assume that $\text{sup }_{x\in U } f(x)\geq \text{sup }_{x\in U}g(x)$. Does this necessarily imply that $\exists x_{0}\in U$ such that $f(x_{0})\geq \text{sup }_{x\in U}g(x)$? For, if suppose  $f(x)< \text{sup }_{x\in U}g(x) \forall x\in U$, then $\text{sup }_{x\in U} f(x)\leq \text{sup }_{x\in U}g(x)$ whence equality of the two suprema hold. Is this a problem? I can't seem to find any contradiction. Once this is proved, the rest of the proof of the theorem follows by using Urysohn's lemma showing that indeed $f=g$.

Comment: As $f(x_0) > g(x_0)$, there is actually an open set $U$ containing $x_0$ such that $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x\in U$.

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are continuous ?

Comment: Yes, they are. Have edited the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the scalar field is $\mathbb{R}$, and $x_0 \in X$ is such that $f(x_0) > g(x_0)$, then choose open intervals $V_1$ and $V_2$ of $f(x_0)$ and $g(x_0)$ respectively such that $V_1\cap V_2 = \emptyset$. Now set
$$
U := f^{-1}(V_1)\cap g^{-1}(V_2)
$$
and note that $x_0 \in U$, so $U$ is a non-empty open set. Let $V$ be an open neighbourhood of $x_0$ such that
$$
V \subsetneq \overline{V} \subsetneq U
$$
Now by Urysohn's lemma, there is a $h\in C(X)$ such that
$$
h\equiv 1 \text{ on } V \text{ and } h\equiv 0 \text{ on } X\setminus U
$$
Now note that
$$
\text{Range}(fh) \subset f(U) \subset V_1 \text{ and}
$$
$$
\text{Range}(gh) \subset g(U) \subset V_2
$$
and $V_1\cap V_2 = \emptyset$, which contradicts your assumption.

Comment: $0$ is in the range of both $fh$ and $gh$. In the last sentence, all your inclusions are backward.

Comment: Yes, I have the same doubt. $\text{Range}(fh)=\{(fh)(x):x\in X\}=\{0\}\cup\{f(x)h(x):x\in U\setminus V\}\cup\{f(x):x\in V\}.$ How does the inclusion $\text{Range}(fh)\subset f(U)$ follow?